# Filtering df on entire row

Tags: python, filter

I have a dataframe with lots of coded columns. I would like to filter this df where a certain code occurs in any column. I know how to filter on multiple columns, but due to the shear number of columns, it is impractical to write out each column.

E.g. if any column contains x, keep that row.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using a boolean mask?

```
value = # the code you are looking for
df =  # whatever ...
mask = df[df.columns[0]] == value
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    mask |= df[col] == value

df2 = df[mask]
```